# Apache: Created Headers in .htaccess file sent twice when requesting PHP file

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-headers

I am trying to set up a .htaccess file with the following content with Apache 2.2.31:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
```

This is working fine but not for PHP files. The Header is sent twice. I created an **empty** HTML file and an **empty** PHP file. For the HTML file the header is sent correctly but when I request the PHP file the header appears twice in the response.

If I drop the `always` keyword the header is sent once but not at all if an errors occurs.

There are no other rewrites/redirects defined.
Unfortunately I do not have access to the Apache core configuration but maybe someone got the same problem so I can contact my provider.

Comment: Yes, contact your hoster anyway. Such issues depend on the SAPI, and FastCGI wrappers for instance.

Comment: Ok, I tried to figure out what I am doing wrong for too long now. :(

Comment: Is this true across browsers? I know of some instances with Google Chrome that causes PHP pages to load twice if invalid headers are given.

Comment: With the latest versions of Chrome and Opera I get the same reults. Microsoft Edge merges the value like "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload, max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload". Firefox displays surprisingly only one value, but I think it is ignoring the first one. With some other request tools I get the header twice, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I changed the hoster. Now everything works well. I do not know what the problem was exactly. But my hoster did not care about that and I decided to switch to another one.

Comment: Too late, but here my 2 cents for others. I had this problem, too. The header was sent twice because it was declared in `.htaccess` AND in apache's configuration file.